# Include belonging into model

Tags: pandas, neural-network, linear-regression

If you had data like (prices and market-cap are not real)

```
Date        Stock   Close   Market-cap   GDP
15.4.2010   Apple    7.74       1.03     ...
15.4.2010   VW      50.03       0.8      ...
15.5.2010   Apple    7.80       1.04     ...
15.5.2010   VW      52.04       0.82     ...
```

where Close is the y you want to predict and Market-cap and GDP are your x-variables, would you also include Stock in your model as another independent variable as it could for example be that price building for Apple works than differently than for VW.

If yes, how would you do it? My idea is to assign 0 to Apple and 1 to VW in the column Stock.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 0):

You first need to identify what exactly are you trying to predict. As it stands, you have longitudinal data such that you have **multiple measurements from the same company** over a period of time.

- Are you trying to predict the `close price` based on `market cap + GDP`?
- Or are you trying to predict the `future` close price based on `previous` close price measurements?

You could stratify based on company name, but it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. What is the question you are trying to answer ?

You may also want to take the following considerations into account:

- close prices measured at different times on the same company are correlated with each other.
- correlations between two measurements soon after each other will be better than correlations between two measurements far apart in time.

There are [four assumptions](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/R/R5_Correlation-Regression/R5_Correlation-Regression4.html) associated with a linear regression model:

- **Linearity**: The relationship between X and the mean of Y is linear.
- **Homoscedasticity**: The variance of residual is the same for any value of X.
- **Independence**: Observations are independent of each other.
- **Normality**: For any fixed value of X, Y is normally distributed.

Comment: Changed the question, so it should make more sense.